# Using template type as argument to std::invoke

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Consider this code:

```cpp
using namespace std;

struct FS
{
    void print() { cout << "p\n"; }
    int s;
};

template <typename T, typename F>
void myInvoke(T& t, F f)
{
    invoke(f, t) = 10;
}

int main(int, char**) 
{
    FS fs;

    myInvoke(fs, &FS::s);

    cout << fs.s << "\n";
}
```

Is there anyway to avoid the runtime cost of passing the **class member pointer** to **myInvoke**?

I can of course do:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void myInvoke(T& t)
{
    invoke(&T::s, t) = 10;
}

// then call with
myInvoke(fs);
```

What I'd like to do:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename P, P FS::* f>
void myInvoke(T& t)
{
    invoke(f, t) = 30;
}

// call with:
myInvoke<FS, int ,&FS::s>(fs);
```

But without the **typename P**. Is there any way to make the call more concise so it can be called with:

```cpp
myInvoke<FS, &FS::s>(fs);
```

I know this is a bit arcane, but it'd be really nice to be as concise as possible. Especially when you have widely used library functions.

EDIT:
Link to sandbox above code: https://godbolt.org/z/z4cGdPd3r

Comment: Are you stuck with C++17?  C++20 introduced `auto` to be used in templates to auto deduce non-type template parameters.

Comment: @NathanOliver: using `auto` in NTTPs is a C++17 feature, not C++20. C++20 lets you use a class template name and have its parameters deduced from the argument.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh yeah, whelp I guess I should just post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for deduced Non-type [template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) (with `auto`) (C++17):

```
template <auto F, typename T>
void myInvoke(T& t)
{
    invoke(F, t) = 10;
}
```

with usage:

```
myInvoke<&FS::s>(fs);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z5Pr7qo56)